# Gamma GLM: why log-link is more common than canonical link

Tags: generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, link-function

"The canonical link of Gamma GLM is $g(x)=1/x$ is often not very practical. Log-link is more appropriated in most cases." One reason I can think of is that log-link makes sure $\mu$, the mean, is always greater than zero. (please correct me if I'm wrong.) But I believe there are other considerations.

So why people often choose the log-link over the canonical one? Is it related to the fact that $\log$ transformation stabilizes data variance?

Comment: who are you quoting?

Comment: Quoting my class instructor, Prof. Hans Muller.

Comment: The prime reason would be that you expect that the logs of the conditional means are linear in the supplied predictors.

Answer (score 5):

A good question. I see the following reasons:

- A log link produces a multiplicative model on the original scale and is thus easy to interprete. This is not true for the canonical link of the Gamma GLM.
- In insurance pricing, the expected claim amount $E(L)$ is often decomposed into $E(L) = E(F)E(S)$, where $F$ is the claim frequency and $S$ the claim height. If both $E(F)$ and $E(S)$ are modeled by GLMs with log link, the coefficients of both models can be easily combined to determine the effects on the expected loss $E(L)$.
- Not using the canonical link introduces a prediction bias on the original scale, i.e. the average prediction differs from the average response. This would be a reason against the log link. However, in my experience, this bias is small with the log link and can easily be fixed by a multiplicative correction factor.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give more detail on "decomposed into a product of a claim count regression and a claim height regression"? And what is "prediction bias"?